# Azure DevOps Trigger: determining which trigger path was triggered

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

If my yaml file has multiple trigger paths defined, is it possible to determine which of the triggers was fired?

Example:

```
trigger:
  branches: 
    include:
    - '*'
  paths:
    include:
    - folder1/documentation1.xml
    - src
```

In this particular case, I want a particular job/step/task to execute if i know that `folder1/documentation1.xml` was changed/triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box such feature. you can install the [Changed files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-changed-files) custom build task:

```
jobs: 
  - job: check
    displayName: Check changed files
    pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: ChangedFiles@1
        name: CheckChanges
        inputs:
          rules: folder1/documentation1.xml
          variable: HasChanged

  - job: build
    displayName: Build only when code changes
    dependsOn: check
    condition: eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.HasChanged'], 'true')
    steps:
        - # Add your build steps here
```

Or write your own script that check the changed files via `git diff` command.